# Pushing Elements into an Array That Is Inside a Callback Function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, nightwatch.js

So I'm using nightwatch for this and can't seem to push elements to an array that is inside a callback. It's showing "undefined".

```
            var tab = [];

            exports.command = function (control,tabs)
            {
                var self=this;
                var split = tabs.split("~"); //DELIMIT "tabs" PARAMETER

                self.elements('css selector', control+" :first-child", function (result) //COUNT THE CHILD OF PARENT
                {
                    var x = result.value;
                    var screenTabLen = x.length; //GET THE LENGTH OF ACTUAL TABS IN THE SCREEN
                    var tabLen = split.length; //GET THE LENGTH OF DELIMITED "tabs"     

                    function getTabText(index)
                    {
                        self.getText(control + " > :nth-child(" + index + ")", function(result){
                            tab.push(result.value);             
                        });

                    }

                    for (i=1; i<screenTabLen; i++)
                    {
                        getTabText(i);
                    }

                    console.log("TAB >> " + tab[1]);

                });

            };
```

how do I resolve this? thanks in advance!
**EDIT:** Pasting the whole code

Comment: what's tab? You only initialize a bat array

Comment: It's a typo. You're pushing to `tab` when you're supposed to be pushing to `bat`.

Comment: You can prevent mistakes like this in the future by using a linter, such as [ESLint](https://github.com/eslint/eslint).

Comment: you still have a typo.. in console.log() it is still bat

Answer (score 0):

Change `tab.push()` to `bat.push()` or change all `bat` to `tab`

```
var bat = []; // global variable

function getTabText(index) {
    self.getText(control + " > :nth-child(" + index + ")", function(result) {
        bat.push(result.value); // push values to array          
    });    
}

for (i=1; i<screenTabLen; i++) {
    getTabText(i); // loop function 
}

console.log("TAB === " + bat[1]); // getting undefined here
```

Comment: Explain to him what you did different in the answer, not just show code

Comment: @AthMav I updated the console.log. still not working sadly

Comment: are you sure that tab[1] exist? Try to print the whole array. console.log(tab) if you can provide more of the code.

Comment: @YoDawgyDawg i cant see what's wrong but you have tagged it as asyncronous, so it must be it...

Answer (score 0):

You just made a typo :) you are trying to push to tab. But the array you defined is called bat.

```
var bat = []; //global variable
//here is your array called bat. 
            function getTabText(index)
            {
                self.getText(control + " > :nth-child(" + index + ")", function(result){
                    bat.push(result.value); //push values to array 
                    //change the tab to bat and you are good.


                });

            }

            for (i=1; i<screenTabLen; i++)
            {
                getTabText(i); //loop function 
            }

            console.log("TAB === " + bat[1]); //getting undefined here
```

Comment: you still have a typo in your console.log("TAB === " + bat[1]);  this should be tab now.