# How can you resolve promises in multiple nested forEach loops?

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, foreach, async-await

For a "flights" portfolio app, I am trying to generate tickets for each seat in a plane (so that flights are prepopulated with some people). This is part of a function that also prepopulates flights to the database to set up the data. There are calls to the database to check to see if the Flight Number, as well as Confirmation Numbers are unique, and not pre-existing. In the case of flights, if the flight number already exists, the flight just gets dropped. However, I am running into some issues with the asynchronous aspect of regenerating a confirmation number if one already exists when it is in loops. So essentially, the issues I'm having:

1. generateTickets returns an empty tickets array
2. I am not sure how to structure my nested forEach loops to return promises when generating the tickets for each seat, in each row. (In my searches on Stack Overflow, I have found multiple solutions referencing Promise.all with array.map. I've tried to implement these solutions in a variety of ways, but I'm still getting an empty array, and I think I'm just not understanding it well enough.)
3. I am getting: `SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word` on `await generateConfirmationNumber()` - even though generateConfirmationNumber is an asynchronous function

I don't know what to say about what I've tried. It's a lot. I've searched through every link for the first 2-3 pages of Google, I've scoured Stack Overflow trying to find solutions, and then trying to implement them. I think I'm just having a hard time interpreting how their code works, when this has additional complexity. The solutions I have on my browser tab currently are:

- [Why doesn't the code after await run right away? Isn't it supposed to be non-blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302584/why-doesnt-the-code-after-await-run-right-away-isnt-it-supposed-to-be-non-blo/43302656)
- [Pushing Elements into an Array That Is Inside a Callback Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46524381/pushing-elements-into-an-array-that-is-inside-a-callback-function)
- [How to wait a Promise inside a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892863/how-to-wait-a-promise-inside-a-foreach-loop)
- [Why does my async function return an empty array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61787882/why-does-my-async-function-return-an-empty-array)
- [Best way to wait for .forEach() to complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38406920/best-way-to-wait-for-foreach-to-complete)
- [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop)
- [How to return values from async functions using async-await from function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49938266/how-to-return-values-from-async-functions-using-async-await-from-function)

I've been googling and trying to get this to work for 3 days now, and I figured it was time to ask a question. :P So on to the code! (If you see crazy all caps comments, it just helps me notice them easily in the console.)

`createFlight` - Called by router, starts everything.

```
async function createFlight(req, res) {
    create_flights().then(() => {
        console.log('Done')
        res.redirect('/')
    })
}
```

`create_flights` - Async Function that generates a random flight.

```
const create_flights = async() => {
    let flights_array = []
    let flights_with_tickets = []

    for(let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        let airline = randomAirline();
        let origin = randomAirport();
        let destination = randomDestination(origin.code);
        let duration = generateDuration()
        let departure = generateDeparture()
        let departure_date = dateString(departure)
    
        let flight_data = {
            number: generateFlightNumber(airline.code),
            airline: airline.name,
            plane: {
                name: randomPlane()
            },
            origin: origin,
            destination: destination,
            departure: departure,
            departure_date: departure_date,
            duration: duration,
            gate: generateGate(),
            amenities: randomAmenities(duration),
            tickets: []
        }
    
        const flight = new Flight(flight_data);
        flights_array.push(flight)
    }
    
    console.log("FLIGHTS ARRAY")
    console.log(flights_array)
    for(let flight of flights_array) {
        console.log(flight)
        const flight_with_ticket = await returnTicketsAsync(flight)
        console.log(flight_with_ticket)
        if(flight_with_ticket) {
            const record = await returnFlight(flight_with_ticket)
            console.log(record)
            if(record) {
                console.log("Created Flight")
                console.log(record.tickets[0])
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

`returnTicketsAsync` - Waits for the tickets to be generated. This is always console logging an empty tickets value.

```
async function returnTicketsAsync(flight) {
    console.log("ASYNC TICKETS?!?!?!!?")
    let tickets = await generateTickets(flight)
    console.log(tickets)
}
```

`returnFlight` - This checks to see if the flight's confirmation number is already in the database. If it is, we just skip this flight and keep moving on. Otherwise, we save it to the database.

```
const returnFlight = flight => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Flight.find({$or:[{number: flight.number}]}, function(error, records) {
            if(records.length) {
                console.log("Similar flight already exists")
                resolve()
            } else {
                flight.save(function (error, result) {
                    if(error) {
                        console.log("ERROR:" + error)
                        resolve()
                    } else {
                        resolve(result)
                        console.log("Flight " + result.number + " successfully saved.")
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    })
}
```

`generateTickets(flight)` - The source of all my troubles. The Flight has a plane map, with sections (first class, preferred class, economy). Each section has rows with seats.
So I need to loop through first class, preferred class, and economy class, generate the tickets for all the seats. There is one function, `generateConfirmationNumber()` that generates the number, and checks the database for a result. If there's no result, the confirmation number is good to be used, and it returns that. I need to await for that to be done, but I'm getting a SyntaxError here.

```
async function generateTickets(flight) {
    let tickets = []
    let prices = generatePrice()

    const first_class =  await Promise.all(_.map(flight.plane.sections.first_class.rows, async function (row, i, rows) {
        let first_class_tickets = await _.map(row, function(seat) {
            if(!seat.isle) {
                let passenger = generatePassenger()
                let confirmation_number = await generateConfirmationNumber()
                let tickets = {
                    confirmation_number: '',
                    tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
                    data: generateDataNumber(),
                    options: '1ST CL',
                    flight_class: 'first',
                    seat: {
                        isle: seat.letter,
                        number: i + 1
                    },
                    boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
                    price: prices.first,
                    passenger: passenger
                }

                if(passenger.first_name !== '' || passenger.first_name.length > 1) {
                    ticket.confirmation_number = confirmation_number
                }
                console.log(ticket)
                tickets.push(ticket)
            }
        })
    }))

    const preferred_class =  await Promise.all(_.map(flight.plane.sections.preferred_class.rows, async function (row, i, rows) {
        let preferred_class_tickets = await _.map(row, function(seat) {
            if(!seat.isle) {
                let passenger = generatePassenger()
                let confirmation_number = await generateConfirmationNumber()
                let tickets = {
                    confirmation_number: '',
                    tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
                    data: generateDataNumber(),
                    options: 'PREF PLUS',
                    flight_class: 'preferred',
                    seat: {
                        isle: seat.letter,
                        number: i + flight.plane.sections.first_class.total_rows + 1
                    },
                    boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
                    price: prices.preferred,
                    passenger: passenger
                }

                if(passenger.first_name !== '' || passenger.first_name.length > 1) {
                    ticket.confirmation_number = confirmation_number
                }
                console.log(ticket)
                tickets.push(ticket)
            }
        })
    }))

    const economy_class =  await Promise.all(_.map(flight.plane.sections.economy_class.rows, async function (row, i, rows) {
        let economy_class_tickets = await _.map(row, function(seat) {
            if(!seat.isle) {
                let passenger = generatePassenger()
                let confirmation_number = await generateConfirmationNumber()
                let tickets = {
                    confirmation_number: '',
                    tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
                    data: generateDataNumber(),
                    options: 'PREF PLUS',
                    flight_class: 'preferred',
                    seat: {
                        isle: seat.letter,
                        number: i + flight.plane.sections.first_class.total_rows + flight.plane.sections.preferred_class.total_rows + 1
                    },
                    boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
                    price: prices.economy,
                    passenger: passenger
                }

                if(passenger.first_name !== '' || passenger.first_name.length > 1) {
                    ticket.confirmation_number = confirmation_number
                }
                console.log(ticket)
                tickets.push(ticket)
            }
        })
    }))

    console.log("Tickets")
    console.log(ticekts)
}
```

`generateConfirmationNumber` - Just throwing this here, too.

```
async function generateConfirmationNumber() {

    let letters = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ'
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000)
    let confirmation = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)] + letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)] + letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)] + number

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Flight.findOne({'tickets.confirmation_number': confirmation}, (err, result) => {
            if (err) console.log(error)
            else if (result) return resolve(generateConfirmationNumber())
            else return resolve(confirmation)
        })
    })
}
```

I'm at a loss for how to get this working. The goal is simply to generate the tickets, wait for the `generateConfirmationNumber()` to finish, and push all the tickets into a "tickets" array for that flight. Then, return that array so it can be $set to the flight, and so then, the flight can be pushed into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue your codes doesn't work because you try to Promise.all() to a  array of the `ticket` below.
Promise.all only working on promises object, but you can see the `ticket` itself is not a purely Promise object. Also, the map() function will not await the promise in the loop. If you want to await a promise in a loop, you need to use `for loop`.

```js
let confirmation_number = await generateConfirmationNumber();
let ticket = {
  confirmation_number: confirmation_number,
  tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
  data: generateDataNumber(),
  options: "1ST CL",
  flight_class: "first",
  seat: {
    isle: seat.letter,
    number: i + 1,
  },
  boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
  price: prices.first,
  passenger: generatePassenger(),
};
```

The below codes doesn't work because ticket is not a promise object.

```js
Promise.all([ticket1,ticket2,ticket3]);
```

To make it work, you have two options.

1. Promises in Parallel: Promise.all all the promises object and use `array#map()` to create a array of ticket objects.
2. Promises in Series: await each promise and construct the ticket one by one.

If you want to do a Promises in Parallel way, you can do like below:

```js
const arrayOfPromises = flight.plane.sections.first_class.rows.flatMap(row =>
  row.map(seat => generateConfirmationNumber())
);

const confirmationNumbers = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);

const tickets = confirmationNumbers.map(cfmNumber => ({
  confirmation_number: cfmNumber,
  tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
  data: generateDataNumber(),
  options: "1ST CL",
  flight_class: "first",
  seat: {
    isle: seat.letter,
    number: i + 1,
  },
  boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
  price: prices.first,
  passenger: generatePassenger(),
}));
```

The answer I use is 2nd option(Promises in Series).

I use for of loop to await each promise and create a ticket from it.
In the end, I add ticket to a array tickets.

```js
async function generateTickets(flight) {
    let tickets = [];
    let prices = generatePrice();
  
    const firstClass = [];
    for (const row of flight.plane.sections.first_class.rows) {
      for (const seat of row) {
        if (!seat.isle) {
          const passenger = generatePassenger();
          const confirmation_number = await generateConfirmationNumber();
          const ticket = {
            confirmation_number: "",
            tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
            data: generateDataNumber(),
            options: "1ST CL",
            flight_class: "first",
            seat: {
              isle: seat.letter,
              number: flight.plane.sections.first_class.rows.indexOf(row) + 1,
            },
            boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
            price: prices.first,
            passenger: passenger,
          };
  
          if (passenger.first_name !== "" || passenger.first_name.length > 1) {
            ticket.confirmation_number = confirmation_number;
          }
          firstClass.push(ticket);
        }
      }
    }
  
    console.log(firstClass);
  
    const preferredClassTickets = [];
    for (const row of flight.plane.sections.preferred_class.rows) {
      for (const seat of row) {
        if (!seat.isle) {
          let passenger = generatePassenger();
          let confirmation_number = await generateConfirmationNumber();
          let ticket = {
            confirmation_number: "",
            tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
            data: generateDataNumber(),
            options: "PREF PLUS",
            flight_class: "preferred",
            seat: {
              isle: seat.letter,
              number: flight.plane.sections.preferred_class.rows.indexOf(row) + flight.plane.sections.first_class.total_rows + 1,
            },
            boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
            price: prices.preferred,
            passenger: passenger,
          };
  
          if (passenger.first_name !== "" || passenger.first_name.length > 1) {
            ticket.confirmation_number = confirmation_number;
          }
          preferredClassTickets.push(ticket);
        }
      }
    }
  
    const economyClass = [];
    for (const row of flight.plane.sections.economy_class.rows) {
      for (const seat of row) {
        if (!seat.isle) {
          let passenger = generatePassenger();
          let confirmation_number = await generateConfirmationNumber();
          let ticket = {
            confirmation_number: "",
            tracking_number: generateTrackingNumber(),
            data: generateDataNumber(),
            options: "PREF PLUS",
            flight_class: "preferred",
            seat: {
              isle: seat.letter,
              number:
                flight.plane.sections.economy_class.rows.indexOf(row) +
                flight.plane.sections.first_class.total_rows +
                flight.plane.sections.preferred_class.total_rows +
                1,
            },
            boarding_zone: generateBoardingZone(),
            price: prices.economy,
            passenger: passenger,
          };
  
          if (passenger.first_name !== "" || passenger.first_name.length > 1) {
            ticket.confirmation_number = confirmation_number;
          }
  
          economyClass.push(ticket);
        }
      }
    }
  
    tickets.push(...firstClass, ...preferredClassTickets, ...economyClass);  
    return tickets;
  }
  
  async function generateConfirmationNumber() {
    let letters = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRSTUVWXYZ";
    let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);
    let confirmation =
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)] +
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)] +
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)] +
      number;
  
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Flight.findOne(
        { "tickets.confirmation_number": confirmation },
        (err, result) => {
          if (err) reject(error);
          // else if (result) return resolve(generateConfirmationNumber());
          else if (result) return resolve(result);
          else return resolve(confirmation);
        }
      );
    });
  }
  
  const returnFlight = flight => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      Flight.find(
        { $or: [{ number: flight.number }] },
        function (error, records) {
          if (error) reject(error);
  
          if (records.length) {
            console.log("Similar flight already exists");
            resolve(records);
          } else {
            flight.save(function (error, result) {
              if (error) {
                console.log("ERROR:" + error);
                reject(error);
              } else {
                console.log("Flight " + result.number + " successfully saved.");
                resolve(result);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      );
    });
  };
  
  const create_flights = async () => {
    let flights_array = [];
    //   let flights_with_tickets = [];
  
    for (let i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      let airline = randomAirline();
      let origin = randomAirport();
      let destination = randomDestination(origin.code);
      let duration = generateDuration();
      let departure = generateDeparture();
      let departure_date = dateString(departure);
  
      let flight_data = {
        number: generateFlightNumber(airline.code),
        airline: airline.name,
        plane: {
          name: randomPlane(),
        },
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        departure: departure,
        departure_date: departure_date,
        duration: duration,
        gate: generateGate(),
        amenities: randomAmenities(duration),
        tickets: [],
      };
  
      const flight = new Flight(flight_data);
      flights_array.push(flight);
    }
  
    console.log("FLIGHTS ARRAY");
    console.log(flights_array);
  
    for (let flight of flights_array) {
      const tickets = await generateTickets(flight);
      if (tickets) {
        flight.set({
            tickets: tickets
        })
        const record = await returnFlight(flight);
        console.log(record);
        if (record) {
          console.log("Created Flight");
          console.log(record.tickets);
        }
      }
    }
  };
  
  async function createFlight(req, res) {
    try {
      await create_flights();
      console.log("Done");
      res.redirect("/");
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: This worked! I had to make a few changes, for example, getting the correct index of the flights, adding set, etc. Do you mind elaborating a bit, and helping the changes you made, and where my original fault in logic was? I just want to make sure that myself, or anyone else who stumbles upon this knows what's happening! Thank you again!

Comment: @Lindsay, I added more explanation. Please let me know if you have questions.